# awk sub in specified column

Tags: bash, awk, substitution

I'm trying to remove text before and after different delimiters, in a specific column only, column 3.

First delimiter is semi-colon, second is comma. They exist in unshown columns too.

Input data:

```
chr2L   54273   2L_54273_SNP;rs203207895        A       G       999     PASS    ALTCOUNT=118;DB;REFCOUNT=69     GT      ./.     ./.     0/0 
chr2L   54339   2L_54339_SNP;rs206877787,rs80377533     T       A       999     PASS    ALTCOUNT=114;DB;REFCOUNT=73     GT      ./.     ./.  
chr2L   54587   2L_54587_SNP;rs203534836        A       G       999     PASS    ALTCOUNT=5;DB;REFCOUNT=199      GT      0/0     0/0     0/0
```

Required output:

```
chr2L   54273   rs203207895        A       G       999     PASS    ALTCOUNT=118;DB;REFCOUNT=69     GT      ./.     ./.     0/0 
chr2L   54339   rs206877787     T       A       999     PASS    ALTCOUNT=114;DB;REFCOUNT=73     GT      ./.     ./.  
chr2L   54587   rs203534836        A       G       999     PASS    ALTCOUNT=5;DB;REFCOUNT=199      GT      0/0     0/0     0/0
```

My efforts have focussed on just removing text before (and including) the semi-colon but with no significant results:

```
awk '{ if ($3 == ".*\;//") {$3 = ""; print} else { print }; }' < a > b
sed 's/.*;//' a > b
awk '{ sub(/*.;/,"",$3) }1 ' < a > b
awk '{sub(;/./*,""); print}' < a > b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use something like this:

```
awk '{ gsub(/^.*;|,.*$/, "", $3) }1' file
```

This matches anything from the start of the third field up to a semicolon or anything from a comma to the end of a field and replaces them with an empty string.

One of your problems was that you were using `*.` (incorrect syntax) rather than `.*` (zero or more of any character).

As suggested in the comments (thanks), you might want to make the pattern slightly more strict, for example:

```
/^[^;]*;|,[^,]*$/
```

Which would only match from the start up to the first `;` and from the last `,` to the end. If you're sure that your data always only has one `;` and one `,`, this isn't necessary but is something to be aware of.

If your input is tab-separated then you can preserve the spaces by instructing awk of this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { gsub(/^.*;|,.*$/, "", $3) } 1' file
```

`FS` and `OFS` are the variables used to set the input and output field separators.

Comment: Right, and just for completeness as it may not matter to the OP given his/her sample data - the above will remove to the last semicolon and from the first comma while `gsub(/^[^;]*;|,[^,]*$/, "", $3)` would remove to the first semicolon and from the last comma. Also, to preserve white space the OP could operate on the whole record instead of one field `sub(/[^[:space:]]+;/,""); sub(/,[^[:space:]]+/,"")`.

Comment: @Ed thanks, updated to include your advice and add a nasty-looking sed option which preserves the spaces.

Comment: @EdMorton @TomFenech Thanks for the help. I plumbed with `awk '{ gsub(/^.*;|,.*$/, "", $3) }1' < a | awk '{gsub(" ","\t");print}' > b` as the input file was actually tab-delimited. `sed -E 's/^(([^ ]+ +){2})[^;]+;([^,]+)(,[^ ]+)*/\1\3/'` a > b didn't alter anything, even when replacing whitespace with \t.

Comment: @Sarah your plumbing is the equivalent of hooking the output of your water heater up to the input of a second water heater to get warmer water. Don't do that, just replace the original water heater with one better water heater. In this case just add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` at the front of your awk script so awk knows your input and output are tab-delimited. And don't use input redirection as it blocks awk from using `FILENAME` and isn't extensible to 2 or more input files. Use `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} { gsub(/^.*;|,.*$/,"",$3) }1' a`

Comment: not sure I understand `(*plumped... plummed???)` but the word is `plumbed` derived from the French word `plomb` meaning `lead` (the metal pronounced "led") since back in the day water pipes etc were made of lead so the people who installed them were known as plombiers/plumbers.